# Telegram Bot Web App not working with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to implement a [Web App](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps) in my Telegram Bot, but I have a problem.

My web app **doesn't work in *Telegram***, but **everything works fine in any browsers**. Moreover, everything worked fine when I created the "Hello World" test application, but when I added more functionality, I get a blank page.

I tried debugging in the way described in the documentation, but I found absolutely no errors. I see that the resources are simply loaded and nothing happens further, as if the *js* is not running at all.

I don't understand the reason at all and where to look for it in my case...

Any help is welcome

[image]

Comment: It's possible that the embedded browser is quite old and so has old syntax support for JS. You could try altering the build of your app such that its compiled to a lower target.

Comment: @AdamThomas I'll try when I get the possibility. But I think that in this case I would see at least some errors

Comment: So the console is completely empty? What are you using to attach the debugger out of interest?

Comment: @AdamThomas I'm using official [manual](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#testing-web-apps) for linux. Basically I'm using the standard dev tools like in the common browser

Comment: Console is completely empty

Comment: Gotcha. Might be worth putting in some logging to see if your components execute. Theres another possibility here in that its actually to do with CSS pushing it off screen or similiar. Need to see if it executes the components or not.

Comment: @AdamThomas There are such logs, the components do not work. But I'll see what happens if I add more logs, but probably already tomorrow

Comment: Often, this can happen when youve got a return null somewhere which is being hit for some deeper reason, i.e. its not fetching network properly. Is it possible the network requests dont work in telegram because of, say, CORS reasons? Check network tab.

Comment: What about from the computer? Is it fine there? Also, is your domain valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the problem.

I generated links with a double slash, for example - `https://example.com//some/path`. Because of this, the [router](https://reactrouter.com/) did not recognize it correctly. In the end, I just corrected the generation of links, and also fixed the router so that it could understand such links.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the webpage does not open inside the telegram bot, but opens in browser. And I am able to fix it.

1. Make sure the web page is served over SSL/TLS. with a name not Ip address.
2. Make sure you have used your certificate chain instead of just the certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I already found what was the problem. See the accepted answer